# Symfony 2 routing: UrlGenerator generates wrong relative urls

Tags: php, symfony, routes, components

I'm using the `Symfony2` components with the `Symfony2` routing component.
My routes.yml includes another specific sub-app-routes.yml:

```
subapp:
    resource: "etc/subapp_routes.yml"
    prefix: /subapp
```

The sub-app-routes.yml has the entries:

```
subapp_calculations_list:
pattern: /calculations
defaults:     { _controller: 'My\Project\Controller\Subapp\Calculations::listAction' }
requirements:
    _method: GET

subapp_calculations_result:
pattern: /calculation/{id}/result
defaults:     { _controller: 'My\Project\Controller\Subapp\Calculations::resultAction' }
requirements:
    _method: GET
```

...which works quite well so far.

Then, I'm using the `Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator` to generate a url from the subapp_routes.yml:

```
        $requestContext = new RequestContext($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        $router = new Router(
            new YamlFileLoader(new FileLocator(array('.'))),
            "etc/routes.yml",
            array(),
            $requestContext
        );

        $this->urlGenerator = new UrlGenerator($router->getRouteCollection(), $requestContext);
```

[...]

```
    public function getRoute($route, $vars = array()) {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate($route, $vars);
}
```

And in the (php)template:

```
<a href="<?= $this->getRoute('subapp_calculations_result', array('id' => $job['job_id'])) ?>">
```

But it always returns the current path concatenated with the absolute path of the generated url.

Example:
I'm at

```
(http://) project/subapp/calculations
```

I'm generating within the template the url for something located at

```
(http://) project/subapp/calculations/123/results
```

Then the url generator returns

```
(http://) project/subapp/calculations/subapp/calculations/123/results
```

...which is of course wrong.

I've also tried to change the `ABSOLUTE_PATH` to `ABSOLUTE_URL` which is the same just with the hostname at the first part.

Some ideas why `symfony 2` generates so strange urls?

Comment: could you add the code youre using for ... "Then i'm using the Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator to generate a url from the subapp_routes.yml but it returns always the current path concatenated with the absolute path of the generated url." ... please?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, added the missed code snippet above.

Comment: I've tracked it down now... The "problem" is fixed if i'm construct the $requestContext = new RequestContext(); without the "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']". Then the symfony2 routing doesn't have the context and so it can't put a "baseUrl" in front of the routing url. But i'm not sure if this is the correct behavior because i've expected a different behavior but okay... now it's working for me.